# Real continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha>1$, $f: R \rightarrow R$ 
find all the continuous functions that satisfy:
$f(x)+f(\alpha x) =x $ $\forall x\in R$
can you give me some tip for this exercise?

Comment: I don't have  a proof yet but I think the only solution is $f(x)=\frac x {1+\alpha}$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $f(0)=0$. Let $g(x)=f(x)-\frac x {1+\alpha}$. Then $g(0)=0$.  Verify that $g(x)+g(\alpha x)=0$. Iteration gives $g(x)+(-1)^{n}g(\alpha^{n}x)=0$. Replace $x$ by $\frac x {\alpha^{n}}$ and let $n \to \infty$ to get $g(x)=0$.

Comment: Kavi. Very nice!